# How to update my Django database with rss feed every X minutes?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-views, rss

Am working new with RSS feed

For every x minutes, i want to add things to my database from rss feed if it has any new things in that. I have written the code to fetch and update in database but how to make that code run for every X minutes.
If i put the piece of code inside one of my views function which renders home page, it slows down the page loading speed. I want it to happen automatically every x minutes without affecting my website functionality.

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article,Slide
import feedparser

rss = feedparser.parse('url am passing')
already_updated = False

first_entry = rss.entries[0]
for slide in Slide.objects.all():
    if first_entry.title == slide.title:
        already_updated = True

if not already_updated:
    for entry in rss.entries:
        new = Slide(title = entry.title, article_name = Article.objects.last())
        new.save()
        print(entry['title'])


def test(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    slides = Slide.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'sample/test_amp.html', {'articles':articles, 'slides':slides})
```

Comment: You will have to write code. If you get stuck, post your code together with a specific question!

Comment: Are you using function-based views or class-based views?

Comment: yes i did coding for that. it runs once before starting the server and fetch things from rss and will update database. but i want that to run every 10 mins without affecting the active server website page. can u pls help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to use [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html) library. Once installed, you need to call the scheduler from the app's config file (apps.py) to start when `manage.py runserver` command is run. Once the APScheduler process has started this way, it will run every interval that you have defined. Here is a working example assuming you have an app called `Home`.

Directory structure:

```
Basedir
| - ProjectName
| - Home
| - - __init__.py
| - - admin.py
| - - apps.py
| - - models.py
| - - test.py
| - - views.py
| - - jobs.py
| - - BackgroundClass.py
```

In your `BackgroundClass.py`, you will define a function that is going to be doing the processing part where you get the RSS feed and update the DB using the results.

Home/BackgroundClass.py

```
class BackgroundClass:

    @staticmethod
    def update_db():
        # Do your update db from RSS task here
```

Now in your `jobs.py`, you will define a function/class that will create an instance of `BackgroundScheduler` from APScheduler, that keeps running in the background indefinitely every X intervals that you define. Using this, you will call your `update_db` function from the `BackgroundClass`.

Home/jobs.py

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from .BackgroundClass import BackgroundClass


def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(BackgroundClass.update_db, 'interval', minutes=1)
    scheduler.start()
```

Now in the `apps.py`, you are going to call that function/class defined in `jobs.py` to run when `manage.py runserver` command is called, so your background task starts with the server, and keeps running as long as the server is running; executing every X intervals.

Home/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class HomeConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'Home'

    def ready(self):
        import os
        from . import jobs

        # RUN_MAIN check to avoid running the code twice since manage.py runserver runs 'ready' twice on startup
        if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) != 'true':
            jobs.start()
```

Comment: That's working  thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: is there a way for me to contact u for helps pls?

Comment: You can create a new post if the problem is not related to this topic. Otherwise you can comment here and I will see what I can do.

Comment: Yeah okay sure..

Comment: What's the difference between AsyncIOScheduler and BackgroundScheduler? I hosted my Django application. BackgroundScheduler is working fine in local server but not in hosted server. Should i use AsyncIOScheduler? And every time it runs it fetches old data from feed may be cause of the cache in rss feed?